# Get line number while using grep

Tags: linux, shell, grep, line

I am using grep recursive to search files for a string, and all the matched files and the lines containing that string are printed on the terminal. But is it possible to get the line numbers of those lines too?

Example: presently, I get `/var/www/file.php: $options = "this.target"`, but I am trying to get `/var/www/file.php: 1142 $options = "this.target";`, well where `1142` would be the line number containing that string.

The syntax I am using to grep recursively is `sudo grep -r 'pattern' '/var/www/file.php'`

How do we get results for not equal to a pattern? Like all the files, but not the ones having a certain string.

Comment: The -v flag will show lines that do not match ( grep -v myText MyFile.txt )

Answer (score 690, accepted):

```
grep -n SEARCHTERM file1 file2 ...
```

Comment: I had another quick question, how do we get results for not equal to a pattern. Like all the files but not the ones having a certain string?

Comment: that would be command line switch -v.

If you run 'grep --help' it will display all options

Comment: You don't need `-r` if you specify multiple files. You only need `-r` if you specify directories.

Comment: @JeanPaul - I see same result for both -nr and -n -r. What version of grep are you using ?

$ grep -n -r name * | wc -l
    1984
$ grep -nr name * | wc -l
    1984
$ grep -V
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

Comment: Code only answer, no explanation. :S

Answer (score 185):

Line numbers are printed with `grep -n`:

```
grep -n pattern file.txt
```

To get only the line number (without the matching line), one may use `cut`:

```
grep -n pattern file.txt | cut -d : -f 1
```

Lines *not* containing a pattern are printed with `grep -v`:

```
grep -v pattern file.txt
```

Comment: And last matching line number: `grep -n pattern file.txt | cut -d : -f 1 | tail -1` (you can save this to a variable and use it to e.g tail file from it)

Comment: And to remove the number/colon at the beginning of each string you can use something like: `grep -n pattern file.txt | sed 's/^[0-9][0-9]*://'`

Answer (score 31):

If you want only the line number do this:

```
grep -n Pattern file.ext | gawk '{print $1}' FS=":"
```

Example:

```
$ grep -n 9780545460262 EXT20130410.txt | gawk '{print $1}' FS=":" 
48793
52285
54023
```

Comment: `awk -F: '{print $1}'` also works & you don't need `-r` in `grep` when used on files (only directories can be searched recursively)

Comment: How to separate `awk '{print $1}' FS=":"` results and save them in a variable for future manipulations?

Answer (score 13):

```
grep -A20 -B20 pattern file.txt
```

Search pattern and show 20 lines after and before pattern

Comment: This is not at all what was asked for.

Comment: Also, `-C20` is a shorter version if that's what was wanted

Comment: Lets face it tough - it's an excelent answer for many of us, who google in here while sifting through log files :)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart That may not have been exactly what the OP asked for, but *I* found it quite useful, and I would encourage folks who answer this type of question to continue adding that sort of tidbit.

Answer (score 2):

**grep -nr "search string" directory**

This gives you the line with the line number.

Answer (score 2):

In order to display the results with the line numbers, you might try this

```
grep -nr "word to search for" /path/to/file/file
```

The result should be something like this:

```
linenumber: other data "word to search for" other data
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with vim you can place

```
function grepn() {
    grep -n $@ /dev/null | awk -F $':' '{t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; }' OFS=$':' | sed 's/^/vim +/' | sed '/:/s// /' | sed '/:/s// : /'
}
```

in your .bashrc and then

grepn SEARCHTERM file1 file2 ...

results in

```
vim +123 file1 : xxxxxxSEARCHTERMxxxxxxxxxx
vim +234 file2 : xxxxxxSEARCHTERMxxxxxxxxxx
```

Now, you can open vim on the correspondending line (for example line 123) by simply copying
`vim +123 file1`
to your shell.